# Geometric Calculus, Clifford Algebra, and Calculus of Variations

Tags: calculus-of-variations, clifford-algebras, geometric-algebras

It has always bothered me that I was told in my Calculus of Variations class  that it's only possible to minimize a function with respect to one objective. Obviously sometimes it *is* possible to minimize with respect to more than one objective, depending on the function and the constraints.

I just started reading about Geometric Calculus yesterday, and woke up this morning thinking that geometric calculus should provide a good approach to dealing with those solvable multiobjective optimization problems, if only because of the peoperties of "antimultivectors".  In particular, it seems that Geometric Calculus might be just right for describing reduced-dimension manifolds in a space of many variables.

Is there a good paper, or set of papers, that describe such an approach to optimization?

Comment: What is an antimultivector? (I know what multivectors are.)

Comment: If I understand correctly, an antimultivector is a blade of grade (n-m) where n is the dimensionality of the space.  It transforms like a pseudovector.  The term "antimultivector" doesn't seem to be used much.

Comment: Well then, what is $m$? I guess it's the dimension of a submanifold. It seems that an antimultivector is simply a multivector with a certain relation to another one (perhaps by multiplication by the tangent blade). I do see the words with "pseudo" more often than "anti", but I like neither...

Comment: the definition of 'antivector' is helpful -- wikipedia.

Comment: https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Blade_(geometry)  "In a space of dimension n, a blade of grade n − 1 is called a pseudovector[2] or an antivector."  So m would be a different value instead of 1.